# effective way perform custom function inside a delegate method on objC

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

Just a question on how delegates work.

**EDIT:**

Because I may have confused you, here is a structure of my app.

**LocationManager** with some delegate functions.

This class defines some delegate methods like:

```
@protocol LocationManagerDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)locationManager:(LocationManager *)locationManager distanceUpdated:(CLLocationDistance)distance;

@end
```

My **MainViewController** instantiates the LocationManager and implements the functions of the delegate.

```
[LocationManager sharedLocationManager].delegate = self;
```

So, inside the LocationManager there is the function:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

and inside that I am calling a custom function f1, and a delegate function like this:

```
        [self.delegate locationManager:self distanceUpdated:self.totalDistance];
```

The code in the delegate function, implemented in my MainViewController is this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(LocationManager *)locationManager distanceUpdated:(CLLocationDistance)distance {
    self.totalDistanceCovered.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f %@", distance, NSLocalizedString(@"meters", @"")];
}
```

So my question is:

Which of this is more efficient and will not may my app blocks?

*This solution:*

in **LocationManager**

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    ...
                [self.delegate locationManager:self distanceUpdated:self.totalDistance];
    ...
    f1();
    }
```

in **mainViewController**

```
- (void)locationManager:(PSLocationManager *)locationManager distanceUpdated:(CLLocationDistance)distance {
    self.totalDistanceCovered.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f %@", distance, NSLocalizedString(@"meters", @"")];
}
```

**OR**

in **LocationManager**

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
...
            [self.delegate locationManager:self distanceUpdated:self.totalDistance];
...
}
```

in **mainViewController**

```
- (void)locationManager:(PSLocationManager *)locationManager distanceUpdated:(CLLocationDistance)distance {
    self.totalDistanceCovered.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f %@", distance, NSLocalizedString(@"meters", @"")];

f1();
}
```

Or are they completely identical?

By that I mean that it will be implemented as a delegate method and the actual code will be in my mainViewController. (move the logic outside my didUpdate - and have it in my mainViewController)is it better? Because right now inside my didUpdate I am performing some extra things. Or is it the same?

When a delegate method is called, does the place from where is it called stall and wait for the completion or it continues and runs independently from the delegate method?
(I am having in my mind that it may be assigned to a different thread for example, so it does not stall - and therefore my did update will not wait for my custom function to finish but it will continue getting updates for locations).

Can you help me?

Comment: Can you post the code that is doing the label updating? Make sure that it is being run on the main thread. Also I may be confused, but are you creating your own `LocationManagerDelegate` and also using `CLLocationManagerDelegate`?

Comment: @nick I will update the post yes in a min, but the code is just a [self.labelname setText:...]. My actual question whether it  is the same that the custom function will be called in the LocationManager or from my MainViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you supply a delegate method, the thread that was running that needed to call your delegate is blocked until your method returns (assuming they are not specifically implementing their call an an asynchronous callback).

If your delegate method updates a UI-related item, as yours seems to, you have an issue because UI-related items must be handled on the main thread.

The way to avoid a performance problem is to have your delegate be a "model" object - not something calling into UI kit.  You should have a separate NSNotification listener, say updateUIFromModel, which is signalled whenever your model is updated to an extent that the UI needs updating.  This listener should be scheduled from the main thread, so it only updates the UI-related items on the main thread.  When your location related delegate is called, you can issue a notification for your listener to pick up and update the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Invoking a delegate method is no different than invoking any other method. Whatever thread invoked the method is the thread that method will run in.

That being said, any sort of UI updating (you mentioned a label) *must* happen on the main thread or you will see some weird results.

Edit:

This is a common pattern when dealing with delegation between threads.

```
- (void)main {

    // This is running some code on a background thread.

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        // This is the main thread. Notify the delegate here.

        if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(finishedDoingBackgroundWork)]) {

            [delegate finishedDoingBackgroundWork];
        }
    });
}
```